# What's the most efficient way to change the overall theme of the app?

Tags: java, android, image, view, android-button

So I got an idea for an app that would change visual theme based on user's selection, something like how a Sub-Reddit would have the option for users to switch between themes. In this case, I would utilize at least 4 themes, each theme changing the color of certain views, such as the background, buttons, image, and etc. I would like to know the the best approach to this. Do I need to keep a list of views that would be affected or something?

I've tried keeping different button backgrounds with different color since setting background color programmatically would reset the background shape back to the default design, but I'm afraid that it will cause the app to be bloated with numerous files. I've tried using the color filter to change the views.

Color id still keeps the filter applied to it, causing it be unusable if user switch to different color, then back.

Comment: They invented [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS) just for this.

Comment: In fact I am pretty sure subreddits do use CSS to switch their themes as well.  So it is _exactly_ what you are talking about.

Comment: Something similar to that, yes, but native Android apps doesn't have CSS support yet as far as I know. This is for changing views within the android apps, not a webview.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, this question was directed at native development. If so, then you should take a look at the [guidelines](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes). You can create your themes in XML and reference them in your layout XML files.

Personally, I would store the theme as a `SharePreference` somewhere and then when laying out each Activity/Fragment, utilize the user's saved theme.

Comment: I'm more thinking along the line of the app have an area where there's a list of themes to pick from, and whenever a new theme is picked, certain parts, such as the buttons and toggle button color changes without interrupting the user's experience. I'm using single activity architecture, and some fragments have forms for user input, and I don't want the user to lose progress on the data they already typed in. My question is what is the best way to change the views that need to reflect the selected theme, whenever a new theme is chosen.

Comment: Yes I understand what you're saying however, my answer still stands. I assume you have a list of themes that they can choose from? If so, these themes should come from XML. And their Theme preference could be stored and used throughout the app. The fact that you are using fragments doesn't matter. What matters is applying whatever theme you have defined in your styles to your views, fragments, and activities. Please read this article for examples of what I am saying:

https://medium.com/mindorks/mastering-android-themes-chapter-1-4aadfa750ca7